# SQLAlchemy giving Error no such column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hello I am new for SQLAlchemy.

I have created Table Row and created using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`. After I changed `no_of_row` into `no_of_seats`, I then get the error

> no such column: rows.no_of_seats

What should I do?

Comment: It means there is no column by that name. There are more than a million causes. Asking doesn't magically fix your problem, especially when we have no clue of what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `rows.no_of_row` worked before:

1. Change a column name in the database, so that it is in sync with the model.
2. If you have no data in your database (or you can spare it), and you did not change table names, just call `Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)`, and then `create_all(..)` again